# Changing one item in a mapped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to show a pause icon only on the track that's playing. For nonplaying tracks,
show a play icon.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (!artistId) return setTracks([])
if (!accessToken) return
let cancel = false
spotifyApi.getArtistTopTracks(artistId, 'US').then(res => {
  let icon = value ? '/icons8-pause-30.png' : '/icons8-play-30.png'
  if (cancel) return
  setTracks(res.body.tracks.map((track) => {
```

**If value === true, grab that one track and make its icon '/icons8-pause-30.png'. And for every other track, make the icons remain '/icons8-play-30.png' Right now, every item's icon is either play or pause.**

```
    return (
      <div onClick={() => setPlayingTrack(track)}>
      <button className='track' onClick={toggleValue} key={track.id}>
        <img className='icon' src={icon} />
        <TrackImg src={track.album.images[0].url} />
        <TrackName>{track.name}</TrackName>
      </button>
      </div>
    )
  }))
})
}, [artistId, accessToken, value, playingTrack])
```

Comment: What is in `value` ? and how does it relate to the tracks ?

Comment: I built a custom hook that toggles between playing and pausing tracks the user clicks on.
`const [value, toggleValue] = useToggle(false)`
If value === true, the track the user clicked on is playing in the spotify player.

Comment: Yes, but with a true/false value you do not know **which** track is currently playing (*you only know that **some** track is playing*). Do you have that information stored somewhere ?

Comment: I see, I set state for the clicked track called setPlayingTrack.

`const [playingTrack, setPlayingTrack] = useState`

Then, I setPlayingTrack to an onClick in the return of the tracks I map through.

Comment: I think I'm figuring this out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this working implementation that makes use of napster api instead of spotify,  *( the logic is the same once you retrieve the array of tracks )*, to see how to manage this scenario.
You are going to save at state the `currentIndex` of the song that is chosen, and an `isPlaying` state toggled when the track is played or paused, this way you can check wheter each track is playing or not `idx === currentIdx && isPlaying` and add styles, icons, etc... accordingly, in a declarative way, you can check the code and working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-audio-ref-classic-test-fix?file=src%2FApp.js:

```
// App.js

const API_KEY = 'MWNjYjY1NGQtMTU1NS00YTM0LWFlZWItYWZkYzdiMTJiZTll';
const URL = 'https://api.napster.com/v2.2/artists/Art.28463069/tracks/top';

export default function App() {
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
  const [currentSongIdx, setCurrentSongIdx] = useState(-1);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef();

  //FETCH TRACKS
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNapster();

    async function fetchNapster() {
      const res = await fetch(URL, {
        headers: {
          apikey: API_KEY,
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setTracks(
        data.tracks.map(({ albumName: name, previewURL: src }) => ({
          name,
          src,
        }))
      );
    }
  }, []);

  //HANDLERS

  function handleNextSong() {
    setCurrentSongIdx((curr) => (curr + 1 === tracks.length ? 0 : curr + 1));
  }
  function handlePrevSong() {
    setCurrentSongIdx((curr) => (curr - 1 < 0 ? tracks.length - 1 : curr - 1));
  }

   function handlePlay() {
    audioRef.current.play();
    setIsPlaying(true);
  }

  function handlePause() {
    audioRef.current.pause();
    setIsPlaying(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current?.addEventListener('canplay', handlePlay);
    return () => audioRef.current?.removeEventListener('canplay', handlePlay);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>CURRENT SONG:</h4>
      <h5>{tracks[currentSongIdx]?.name}</h5>
      <Controls
        handleNextSong={handleNextSong}
        handlePrevSong={handlePrevSong}
        handlePlay={handlePlay}
        handlePause={handlePause}
        audioRef={audioRef}
      />
      <div>
        {tracks?.map(({ name }, idx) => (
          <TrackInfo
            key={name + idx}
            isSelected={idx === currentSongIdx}
            data={{ name }}
            setCurrentSongIdx={setCurrentSongIdx}
            idx={idx}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      ;
      <Audio src={tracks[currentSongIdx]?.src} audioRef={audioRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Audio.js

function Audio({ src, audioRef }) {
  return (
    <>
      <audio ref={audioRef} src={src} />
    </>
  );
}

// TrackInfo.js  -- This is where you show info and apply styles, icons, etc...

function TrackInfo({
  data: { name },
  isSelected,
  setCurrentSongIdx,
  idx,
  isPlaying,
}) {
  const icons = ['▶️', '⏹️'];

  const handleTrackClick = () => {
    setCurrentSongIdx(idx);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{icons[isPlaying && isSelected ? 1 : 0]}</span>
      <span
        onClick={handleTrackClick}
        style={{ color: isSelected ? 'green' : 'red', cursor: 'pointer' }}
      >
        ALBUM: {name}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}


// Controls.js

function Controls({
  handleNextSong,
  handlePrevSong,
  handlePlay,
  handlePause,
  audioRef
}) {
  const [perc, setPerc] = useState(0);
  //ADD LISTENERS

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUpdate = ({ target }) =>
      setPerc(calcPerc(target.currentTime, target.duration));
    audioRef.current?.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleUpdate);
    return () =>
      audioRef.current?.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleUpdate);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlePlay}>PLAY</button>
      <button onClick={handlePause}>PAUSE</button>
      <button onClick={handleNextSong}>NEXT</button>
      <button onClick={handlePrevSong}>BACK</button>
      <span>{bar(perc)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

function bar(perc) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: perc ? perc + "%" : 0,
        height: "20px",
        background: "#000"
      }}
    >
      <h5 style={{ color: "#FFF" }}>{perc}%</h5>
    </div>
  );
}

//HELPER

const calcPerc = (curr, total) => {
  return Math.floor((curr * 100) / total);
};

function Equalizer({ audioRef }) {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //NEED JUST A REF TO CANVAS AND TO THE AUDIO ELEMENTS
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const audio = audioRef.current;
    //INIT CANVAS CONTEXT
    const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.6;
    //INIT AUDIO CONTEXT AND ANALYSER
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const analyser = new AnalyserNode(context, { fftsize: 2048 });
    //GET AUDIO SOURCE
    const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    //DATA USED TO DRAW THE GRAPH
    const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    //POPULATE THE dataArray
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
    //NAME OF ANIMATIONFRAME TO CALL TO CANCEL THE DRAWING
    let animation;

    audio.onplay = draw;
    audio.onpause = () => cancelAnimationFrame(animation);

    function draw() {
      console.log("PLAYING");
      animation = requestAnimationFrame(draw);

      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

      canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
      canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";

      canvasCtx.beginPath();

      var sliceWidth = (canvas.width * 1.0) / bufferLength;
      var x = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        var v = dataArray[i] / 100.0;
        var y = (v * canvas.height) / 2;

        if (i === 0) {
          canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
          canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        x += sliceWidth;
      }

      canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
      canvasCtx.stroke();
    }

    return () => {
      audio.onplay = null;
      audio.onpause = null;
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of React's lifecycle functionality. Instead of setting `icon` as a let value you need to keep it in `state` and `setState` accordingly.

Add this to the top of your component:

```
const [icon, setIcon] = useState('/icons8-play-30.png');
```

Then in the `useEffect` you need to replace:

```
let icon = value ? '/icons8-pause-30.png' : '/icons8-play-30.png'
```

with

```
setIcon(value ? '/icons8-pause-30.png' : '/icons8-play-30.png')
```